# PostGIS feature compare function?

Tags: postgis, comparison

I would like to be able to compare features in Layer 1 (source) to features in Layer 2 (updates to source) in order to see if any of the features geometry and/or attributes have changed.  I would also then like have a "report" generated stating what has changed.

**Edit for Clarification:** Changes in geometry also include finding features that have been added to the new data layer.  Deletions might be interesting to have, but additions are more important.

I've been looking through the PostGIS functions and can't seem to find any tools that are designed to compare and report differences between 2 layers features, both geometry and attributes.

I am looking for something similar to the ArcGIS "[Feature Compare](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=feature_compare_%28data_management%29)" tool.

If there is nothing like this in PostGIS, are there other open-source tools that will answer these types of questions?  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use some kind of versioning system? Or do you already have those two layers and you have to deal with them now?

Comment: It would definitely be easier to use versioning, except that the data is not owned or maintained by me.  It is data that is provided in quarterly updates, in a variety of formats (usually shapefiles), and I want to find out which features and attributes have changed between updates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do row-wise comparisons in PostgreSQL with [row constructors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). I'm guessing that this would work with geometry fields but I haven't tried it.

Given two tables where the matching features have the same id field in each you could do something like:

```
select ROW(t1.att1, t1.att2, t1.geom) = ROW(t2.att1, t2.att2, t2.geom)
from t1, t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```

Update: This does work with geometry fields in my testing.

Update 2:
Here's a more complete example based on your criteria.

Tables:
 t1(id, att1, att2, geom)
 t2(id, att1, att2, geom)

```
-- return the id and geometry from the updated table if the attributes or
-- geometry have changed or it's a new feature.

select t2.id, t2.geom
from t1, t2
where
  ( t1.id = t2.id and row(t1.att1, t1.att2, t1.geom) != row(t2.att1, t2.att2, t2.geom))
  or
  t2.id not in (select id from t1)
```

That *should* get you what you're looking for. You'll probably want to change the 'not in' clause to a 'not exists' for better performance.

Comment: That would ignore any additions or deletions to the dataset (where an id is only present in one table), wouldn't it?

Comment: The question doesn't mention deletes or additions but you could easily union that with a query to find ones that are new or deleted. You could also work in the difference between the features.

Comment: Sean, this is a great concept that looks really promising. 1) This finds all features that are the same, how would I find all the changes? 2) What would be the best method to join this result back to the changed features (geometries), so that you could visually compare the changed features to the source features?

Comment: @Ryan: It finds both - it should return if the rows are identical (True or False) for each pair of identical ids.

Comment: @Sean: I am so very close to making this work, but when I attempted to do a UNION (as I used in the ST_EQUALS answer) to include all of the new geometries, I couldn't get it to work because it said I needed the same number of rows in my union query.  The Row()=Row() creates an boolean column that doesn't exist in my source data (part of the UNION statement), so how do I create/reference a "fake" column in my UNION query to match the ROW()=ROW() select statement?

Comment: You can instead select the columns you want e.g. id, geom. Then put the row()=row() in the where clause. Select the same columns, id and geom in this example, in the unioned query. You can fake a column by selecting the explicit value. e.g. SELECT id, geom, True... or SELECT True where id not in...

Comment: @Sean, thanks for you great update to the code.  When I ran this and made the updates to the table names and attributes, I got the following error: "Could not choose a best candidate operator.  You might need to add explicit type casts", referring to the "!=".  Thoughts?  Running Postgres 9.0.1 and PostGIS 1.5.2.

Comment: As an update to my previous comment, I have determined it is an issue with the "geometry" field.  If I use pure text fields, the query works fine.  If I use "=", the query works fine.  It's just if I include "!=" and the "geometry" field in the row() statement that I get the error.

Answer (score 2):

The function `ST_Equals(geometryA, geometryB)` returns TRUE if they are spatially equal.

Comment: Does this compare two *layers* or just two specific *features*?  Also, what does "spatially equal" mean?  Does it mean that they represent the same set of points on earth, or does it meant that they represent the same set of points *in exactly the same ways*?  (The latter is more stringent.)

Comment: What I really wanted to get as a result were all geometries in layer A (updated) that had been added or changed since layer B (original).  I was able to accomplish that result with the following syntax: 
SELECT A.fields FROM A EXCEPT SELECT A.fields FROM A,B WHERE ST_EQUALS(A.geom,B.geom). The result is all of the feature geometries from layer A that have changed or been added. Thanks!